# Wordpress list results by page title using get_pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom loop working nicely - but i want the loop to list the results in alphabetical order based on post_title - can someone help me update the code below to get it to work please // thanks

```
<?php
$ids = array();
$pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
if ($pages) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $ids[] = $page->ID;
    }
}
$paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
$args = array(
    "paged" => $paged,
    "post__in" => $ids,
    "posts_per_page" => 50000,
    "post_type" => "page"
);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `'orderby' => 'title',` to your query args like below:

```
<?php
$ids = array();
$pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
if ($pages) {
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $ids[] = $page->ID;
    }
}
$paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
$args = array(
    "paged" => $paged,
    "post__in" => $ids,
    "posts_per_page" => 50000,
    "post_type" => "page",
    "orderby" => "title", // ADD THIS
);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```